# Getting/posting multipart data in Node.js

Tags: ios, node.js

I am writing a Node.js server that will communicate with an iOS app where I will be sending both images and text to and from the server. How can I GET/POST multipart requests in my Node app? Any pointers toward resources would be much appreciated. I'm reading a lot about `multipart-form`, but I don't think a form is what I want since I don't have a webpage...thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you post from a HTML form, or using some other kind of mechanism is irrelevant for the server side. It doesn't care who posted, just how it is encoded (multipart-form is correct).

In Node.js, you can use Formidable to decode the incoming data. A basic blueprint would be something like

```
function handleUpload (req, res) {

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm({
        multiples: false,
        uploadDir: uploadDir,
        keepExtensions: true,
        maxFieldsSize: 1024,
        maxFields: 100,
        maxFileSize: maxFileSize,
        maxFormSize: maxFormSize
    });

    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        if (err) {
            logger.debug('Form processing done. Found error: ' + util.inspect(err));
            res.render('error', { error: err});
        } else {
            logger.debug('RECEIVED FIELDS ---------------------');
            logger.debug(util.inspect(fields));
            logger.debug('RECEIVED FILES  ---------------------');
            logger.debug(util.inspect(files));

            res.render('done', { fields: fields, files: files});
        }

    });
};
```

You can find [a complete example here](https://github.com/aweijnitz/EmptyServer.js). I use it a lot as a kind of primitive scaffold for my own projects. It is a small multi-part form upload exampled based on Express4, using Formidable for form parsing. [See this file for details.](https://github.com/aweijnitz/EmptyServer.js/blob/master/routes/upload.js)